# Wrong date in highstock Chart

Tags: javascript, highcharts

How can I incorporate the correct date into my high stock chart? I keep getting the months January to February (correct range should be from July to August) in my slider, which is incorrect. In my PHP I convert the date/time from my database into a JavaScript timestamp, but still doesn't work. Any help would be great, thanks!

Output Array: [data.txt](https://puu.sh/xFFEh/10894baee2.txt)

Current high stocks Chart: [image: highstock line chart]

PHP & JS and HTML:

```js
<?php
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($con, "SELECT date, IFNULL(AT,'null') FROM test");
 $result = array('date' => array(), 'AT' => array());
 if ($stmt) {
  mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
  mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $date, $at);
     while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)) {
         $result['date'][] = $date;
         $result['AT'][] = (int)$at;
            
           $stamp = strtotime($date); // get unix timestamp
           $time = $stamp*1000;       

     }
     mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
       
    }
 
?>
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html > 
    <!--<![endif]-->     
    <head> 
        <meta charset="utf-8"> 
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1"> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/data.js"></script>      

<script>

$(function(data) {
  
     
       
 

     $('#chart2').highcharts('StockChart', {          //Stock chart - might need zones to match gauges
  

      rangeSelector : {
                buttons : [{
                    type : 'hour',
                    count : 3,
                    text : '3h'
                }, {
                    type : 'day',
                    count : 2,
                    text : '2D'
                }, {
                    type : 'week',
                    count : 1,
                    text : '1W'
                }, {
                    type : 'month',
                    count : 1,
                    text : '1M'
                },  {
                    type : 'all',
                    count : 1,
                    text : 'All'
                }],
                selected : 2,
                
            },

      title: {
          text: 'Power'
      },
         

   
      yAxis: [{
          title: {
              text: 'Bat V'
          },
          height: 400,
          lineWidth: 2,
    oposite: true
      }, {
          title: {          // yAxis 1 ie secondary y-axis
              text: 'Solar V'
          },
          //top: 200,
          height: 400,
          offset: 25,
          lineWidth: 2,
    oposite: false
      }],
      
   xAxis:{
     type: <?php echo json_encode($time) ?>,
     
      },  
      
      series: [{
                 pointInterval:  24 * 3600 * 1000,
          type: 'line',
          data:  <?php echo json_encode($result['AT']) ?>
      },],
  });          //end of stockchart graphic

               // end of get function
  
  });           // end of graphing function

</script>         
</head>     
    <body>     
        <?php echo $time; ?>
    <br><br /><br /><br />
    <div id="chart2" style="width:100%; height:600px;"></div>
    </body>     
</html>
```

Comment: hi hokletrain, you posted very similar question about that on Highcharts forum. I sent you request for your topic. Please, take a look on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your Output Array: data.txt which is `[["2017-07-25 16:44",12],["2017-07-25 17:00",12],...]` it should be `[[1500981240000,12],[1500982200000,12],...]` so fix is `$result['date'][] = strtotime($date)*1000` get unix timestamp in milliseconds

```
<?php
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($con, "SELECT date, IFNULL(AT,'null') FROM test");
    $result = array('date' => array(), 'AT' => array());
    if ($stmt) {
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
        mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $date, $at);
        while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)) {
            $result['date'][] = strtotime($date)*1000; // get unix timestamp in milliseconds
            $result['AT'][] = (int)$at;

           $stamp = strtotime($date); // get unix timestamp
           $time = $stamp*1000;       

        }
        mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);

    }

?>
```